# bukkit. Получение координат из GUI/Как достать эти (не буду ругаться) координаты?

Tags: java, gui

Есть у меня GUI.

```js
public class GUI implements Listener {
 public static void OpenGUI(Player p, int x, int y, int z){
  Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, ChatColor.AQUA + "Тестовый GUI");
  
  inv.setItem(0,ItemUtil.create(Material.ANVIL, ChatColor.GREEN + "test"));
  inv.setItem(1,ItemUtil.create(Material.STONE, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "KILLKILLKILL!"));
  inv.setItem(22,ItemUtil.create(Material.WOOD_DOOR, ChatColor.RED + "Выйти"));
  p.openInventory(inv);
  
 }
 
 @EventHandler
 public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e){
  Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
  if(e.getInventory().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.AQUA + "Тестовый GUI")){
   e.setCancelled(true);
  }
  if(e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.RED + "Выйти")
                && e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.WOOD_DOOR){
   p.closeInventory();
  }
  else if(e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.GREEN + "test")
                && e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.ANVIL){
   p.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.GLASS));
   p.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Я у мамы космонавт)");
  }
  else if(e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "KILLKILLKILL")
                && e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.STONE){
   Bukkit.getWorld("world").getBlockAt(0, 0, 0).setType(Material.AIR);
   p.closeInventory();
  }
 }
}
```

В метод открытия самого гуи записываются координаты блока, на который кликнули.

```js
@EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
  if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK){
        Block block = e.getClickedBlock();
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            Block b = a.get(i);
            if (block.getX() == b.getX() && block.getY() == b.getY() && block.getZ() == b.getZ()) {GUI.OpenGUI(p,block.getX(),block.getY(),block.getZ());}
         }
  }
 }
```

Из первого кода видно, что при выборе предмета "KILLKILLKILL", должен разрушиться какой-то таинственный блок с координатами 0,0,0... Но мне нужно вместо нулей получать координаты из гуи, либо посоветуйте и объясните, каким ещё образом можно сохранить координаты этого блока, чтобы передать в тот метод.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение сам. Просто перекинул все координаты в описание (lore) предмета.